# Finding Continuing Numbers in Python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, numbers

First of all, I apologize for my vague question framing, I just couldn't figure out what to call this question. I have also searched google a lot trying to find the solution but I came to no conclusion.

I currently have a whole string with numbers like these `15-5.{123434}.15-18.`. I want to iterate over the string, and as soon as I encounter an opening curly brace I want to take all of numbers after that before encountering a closing brace and put them in a variable. I have thought of a way of doing this, like this:

```
string = '15-5.{123434}.15-18.'
result = ""

for index, letter in enumerate(string):  # For every letter with it's index,
    if letter == '{':  # If letter is '{',
        for number in string[index:]:  # Start a loop from that index,
            if number =='}':  # If number becomes '}',
                break
            result += number  #Else append the number in the result string.
```

However, I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this. I appreciate all of the answers. Thank you!

```
System: Windows 10, 32bit
Python version: 3.6.0
```

Comment: use regular expressions?

Comment: Are you familiar at all with regular expressions?  They make this a trivial problem.

Comment: I was thinking about using regex's but I don't know them well and I don't know if I should use, re.search(), re.match() or any other suitable option.

Comment: Can there be more than one set of curly braces in the same line?

Comment: Use re.finditer() or re.findall().

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the few times I'll recommend a regex:

```
In [27]: for i in re.findall("\{\d+\}", '15-5.{123434}.15-18.'): print(i[1:-1])
123434
```

Of course, you could write a function to parse it yourself:

```
def getNums(s):
    answer = []
    curr = []
    acc = False
    for char in s:
        if char == "{":
            acc = True
            continue
        if char == "}":
            acc = False
            answer.append(''.join(curr))
            acc = False
            continue
        if acc:
            curr.append(char)
```

Comment: Oh! I thought I could solve it with regex's but didn't know which one to use, thanks a lot! But I don't understand why you used the `In` thingy

Comment: @Frixoe: The `In` thingy is just my python terminal. Don't worry about it :)

Comment: @Frixoe you can ignore that.  It's just the prompt for one of the python terminals

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

not knocking a regex but I think I found another one-liner with .split()

```
[e.split('}')[0] for e in s.split('{') if '}' in e]
```

testing:

```
ss = ['','{}','{0}','1','{0}1','1{0}','{0}{2}','{0}1{2}','{0}1{2}3']                      

for s in ss:                       
    print(s,[e.split('}')[0] for e in s.split('{') if '}' in e])
 []
{} ['']
{0} ['0']
1 []
{0}1 ['0']
1{0} ['0']
{0}{2} ['0', '2']
{0}1{2} ['0', '2']
{0}1{2}3 ['0', '2']
```

**edited** to expand on list comprehensions

plenty of info available on list comprehensions, http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ is very basic, enough to understand my answer's list comprehension

we can rewrite the comprehension with line breaks between its parts which may help reading it:

```
c = [e.split('}')[0]
            for e in s.split('{')
                if '}' in e]
```

and we can do the whole thing in the equivalent for loop:

```
def in_curly(s):    
    new_list = []
    for e in s.split('{'):
        if '}' in e:
            new_list.append(e.split('}')[0])
    return new_list

c = in_curly(s)
```

with say:

```
s ='35{0}17{2}3'
```

either or both of the above can be stepped through in http://pythontutor.com live execution visualization mode

Comment: I didn't quite understand that. Sorry, I'm relatively new to comprehensions so a one-liner just looks so confusing.

Comment: added a bit on understanding the list comprehension

Comment: Thanks! I have understood comprehensions! :D